# Sort an 2D array by number of hits

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, jtable

I have two ArrayLists:

Array 01:

```
ArrayList<String> uniqueFiletypes --> which contains unique filetypes (e.g .zip etc..)
```

Array 02:

```
ArrayList<Integer> countFiletypes --> which counts how many of each filetype there is, for example 8 .zip's
```

And to skip right to the question:

I need to make some kind of "ranking", which means the highest count of filetypes gets the first place, etc...

Another problem: It must be an Object[][] (to support JTable), so it is possible to show the result easily.

Example of output: I have 8 .zips, 5 .java and 2 .docx

```
Object[][] = {{"1", ".zip", "8"},{"2", ".java", "5"}, {"3", ".docx", "2"}}
```

Where {PLACE, FILETYPE, COUNT}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the order of the items in both lists matches. I.e. the first item in the uniqueFiletypes list has the number of hits equal to the first number in the countFiletypes  list.

I would do the following:

1. Loop through the lists, adding the entries to a Map.
2. Sort the list of countFiletypes in descending order.
3. Pull the file types from the map, adding them in the order they're now in in the ordered list.

Something like the following might do the trick:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final ArrayList<String> uniqueFileTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
    uniqueFileTypes.add(".java");
    uniqueFileTypes.add(".zip");
    uniqueFileTypes.add(".docx");

    final ArrayList<Integer> countFileTypes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    countFileTypes.add(5);
    countFileTypes.add(8);
    countFileTypes.add(2);

    final Map<Integer, String> countedFileTypes = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    for (int i = 0; i< uniqueFileTypes.size(); i++ ) {
        countedFileTypes.put(countFileTypes.get(i), uniqueFileTypes.get(i) );
    }

    Collections.sort(countFileTypes);
    Collections.reverse(countFileTypes);

    final Object[][] data = new Object[countedFileTypes.size()][3];

    for(int i = 0; i<countedFileTypes.size(); i++) {
        final Integer count = countFileTypes.get(i);
        data[i] = new Object[]{(i+1), countedFileTypes.get(count), count};
        System.out.println("{" + (i+1) + "," + countedFileTypes.get(count) + "," + count + "}");
    }
}
```

The main method and the system out aren't really needed, I just used them for testing my solution, which produced this output:

```
{1,.zip,8}
{2,.java,5}
{3,.docx,2}
```

Granted, this implies a link between the number of hits and the file type which may not be true. For example, if the docx and the java file format both have 9 hits, this solution wouldn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to key off of String in the hashmap instead of the integer count of files types?  If a new file is added or an old one removed then the key for that file type changes.  When the new key value gets added into the map you'll have two different keys mapping to the same string value.  I'd use the string as a unique identifying key and have the integer count as the variable value.

Comment: I was actually working on an extra bit of info that relates to your point @Tansir1. Yes, I did mean to put the map of integer to string as that allows the ordering to get the right value out of the map. However, as I've just added, this will mean that the counts will need to be unique. Using the strings as the identifier is better. To be honest, I'm wondering if there's something available in the Guava Collections classes that would be useful here. [BiMap maybe](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)

Comment: No worries. Keep in mind though "if the docx and the java file format both have 9 hits, this solution wouldn't work." 9 being arbitrary, if they have the same number of hits, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to merge the two `ArrayLists` to a single `HashMap<String, Integer>`? 
This map can hold the entries consisting of the unique filetype (`String`) and its count (`Integer`). I suggest this because you have a direct link between a filetype and its count - this "link" can be expressed by a `HashMap` entry.

The conversion of the HashMap to an Object[][] can be done this way:

```
for (Map.Entry<?,?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    model.addRow(new Object[] { entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() });
}
```

With the HashMap sorting gets also easier as you do not need to handle two independent array lists.

Answer (score 0):

- First approach: As you will work with `JTable`, Use  `TableRowSorter` as shown in the [demo example of tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)
- Second approach: Assuming you need it not only for `JTable`

  ```
  Object[][] array = {{"1", ".zip", "8"},{"2", ".java", "5"}, {"3", ".docx", "2"}};
  List<Object[]>data = Arrays.asList(array);
  Comparator<Object[]>comparator = new Comparator<Object[]>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {

      return ((String)o1[2]).compareTo((String)o2[2]);
    }


  };

  Collections.sort(data, Collections.reverseOrder(comparator));

  array = (Object[][]) data.toArray();
  ```